# Animating slicing up an object

Tags: animation, workflow

I'm animating slicing up something like this along the y axis:

[image: monkey block]

I'm going to shave slices off the front until the whole block is gone.

My understanding is that the only way to do this is by having many pre-sliced meshes, moving them around together as one unit until it's time to make a "cut".

The above approach doesn't work because of the transparency:

[image: monkey block cut]

What is the best approach I could take to animate slices coming off the front of this block?

Comment: I'm currently working on a script that keeps a "slices" list and a "remaining" list. With those, it adds keyframes which toggle visibility to show the next "remaining" mesh as each slice comes off the front. Is there a better way?

Comment: Oop... didn't see your comment when I made my answer. Short version, though: this is animation; it's naturally time-consuming. :P By the time you come up with a better way, you probably could have achieved the effect you're looking for using this method.

Comment: It's seriously hard on the head! Glad to hear I'm on the right track - excited to see how it turns out :)

Comment: A script like that could be massively useful when combined with the Cell Fracture addon for joining different shards and toggling visibility for them on the proper frames.. :)

Comment: @gandalf3, what I'm doing now is quite specific to my my block and the objects inside. If you can describe what a general purpose script would do, I can try to make this as generic as possible!

Comment: @ajwood Maybe this would be different.. (I think it would have to interact with rigid body simulation to know which objects came off first) See my question here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1871/rendering-transparent-objects-with-the-cell-fracture-addon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common trick is to have multiple objects... not just for the slices, but also for the remaining chunks. You animate the visibility of the chunks in succession as each slice is made. This is taking a note from the stop-motion animation world. In effect, you're not animating slices so much as you're swapping in and out the sliced parts in order. When done right, it will look like the slab is being sliced up.

Answer (score 14):

## Dissolve slice

Use a [Boolean modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html#boolean-modifier) with and animated intersection object:

[image: Animated Suzanne dissolve][image: Boolean modifier]

## Chop slice

0. Add a Boolean modifier to your mesh and set the target boolean object.
1. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+select the boolean object and <kbd>Object | Parent | Object</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>).

- You can now use the boolean object to move the mesh without affecting the boolean operation.

0. With them both still selected <kbd>Object | Duplicate Linked</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), cancel the translation (<kbd>Esc</kbd>) and change the [boolean operation type](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html#options) of the new mesh to Difference.

- You should now have two half's that can be moved separately.

0. Finally create a [shape key](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/shape_keys/introduction.html#workflow) on one of the boolean objects that you'll animate to enable/place the boolean/chop.

[image: Animated Suzanne slice]

Comment: This way, I get the "remaining" but lose the "slices." Perhaps it's unclear in the question, but having both is a requirement.

Comment: This is a neat trick though!

Comment: I want to animate shaving slices off the front of the block. To make it realistic, something needs to happen to the pieces that are shaved off, rather than simply disappearing.

Comment: I don't understand how your chop slice works, but it looks promising. Could you elaborate, or point to a tutorial that might explain some things?