# how do I make an object bend or break if hit with sufficient force?

Tags: physics

How can I make a Ridged body simulation mesh so that it's solid under normal conditions, but if a heavy object collides with it, it bends as the force is transferred?
(i.e. like a ball through glass or a bullet through steel)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately, dynamic fracturing/destruction is not truly possible yet. Though there are some interesting experiments:

- [Blender Demolition - Proxy Mesh Utilization (Demo 6)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfdTB2Rrzoc)
- [Real-time Shattering Demolition physics in the BGE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8W_czCvLwJY)
- [BA thread with a patch developed by the author of the above videos](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?207866)

However, you can fake fracturing with the [*Cell Fracture* addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/Fracture) (which is bundled with blender, you can enable it in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>*> Preferences > Addons > Cell Fracture*) and rigid-body contraints:

1. It's not necessary, but you can get finer control over how an object is fractured by using the *Grease Pencil*:

   [image]
2. Fracture the object into separate objects by pressing *Cell Fracture* in *3D view > Tool Shelf*:

   [image]
3. Make them rigid-body objects and constraint them using another [addon called *Bullet Constraints Tools*](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?275823-WIP-Bullet-Constraints-Tools-0-3-7):

   [image]
4. Use the *Calculate Mass* tool to calculate and set the mass of all selected objects based on volume. I used the *Glass (Broken)* preset for the shards and the *Bronze* preset for the monkey:

   [image]
5. Manually animate the render visibility of the original and fractured objects in the *Outliner* (camera icon), so that the original is used until it is fractured by an impact, or use post processing. ([see related post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1871/599))

[image]

You can simulate bending with [soft-bodies](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/soft_body/index.html#soft-body), however tearing is not possible. (though again [there are some tests](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qakuh0ZCjWs))

Comment: where is the greasepencil panel by the way? I can find the draw buttons and such but I can't find the panel with the checkbox and options for it.

Comment: @ZCoder With your object selected, press `N` in the *3D view* to open the *properties region*, then click *new layer* in *3D view > Properties region > Grease Pencil*. The options should appear.

Answer (score 4):

With the fracture modifier branch you can do dynamic fracture by now, but its still a bit WIP.

Would look like this for glass (and with fractal shards, which are optional).
You also could use regular voronoi shards for this.

[image: dynamicglass]

Links to builds are here

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?343637-Custom-Build-Blender-Fracture-Modifier

or here (latest windows build): http://graphicall.org/1148

[image]