# Modelling metal deformation properly

Tags: physics

I'm looking for tips on how to realistically model metal deformation in blender. I would like to have ability to "fasten" a metal plate with virtual "screws" on a frame. Then I want to simulate an impact of another object on this metal sheet and I want the sheet to deform and then eventually I want the imact object to break through the sheet like a metal beam breaking through a sheet of steel. Then I want the sheet to bend realistically while points where the screws are should hold longer and only let go at a certain point when the stress of the sheet becomes to big.

Basically I want to realistically simulate such a situation. If you can give an example using soft bodies then please specify the settings you are using. I have so far not been able to get what I want using soft bodies.

Comment: Unfortunately tearing is not possible atm, see [this related post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6686/599).