# How to get fragments of an exploded object to react more accurately to collisions with a plane?

Tags: animation, particles, physics

Since a picture (or animated GIF in this case) is worth a thousand words, I will begin by providing an example of the problem I am trying to solve:

[image]

As you can see, the fragments of the monkey never change orientation as they fall and "bounce" off of the plane that they are colliding with.

I created this animation by adding a monkey to the scene and using the Object->Quick Effects->Quick Explode tool. The fragments never change their orientation, which is grossly unrealistic.

How do I fix this?

Comment: It is possible to make particles rotate, however I think you want *Rigid-body* physics.

Comment: @gandalf3 Would I add them to the monkey or the cube? I'm not very knowledgeable in Blender, so please excuse me if that's a dumb question.

Comment: The monkey. [Here's the documentation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Sergof/GSoC2012/Documentation).

Comment: [I'm making progress.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UjQcN.gif)

Comment: Related: [how do I make an object bend or break if hit with sufficient force?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6686/599)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the explosion shards/particles rotate dynamically by enabling *Rotation* and *Dynamic* in the particle settings:

[image]

### Result:

[image]

However, if you want realism I recommend you try the *Cell fracture* addon with *rigid body physics*. See [this question for more info](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6686/599).