# How can I create a soft, fluid filled pod that can rupture?

Tags: animation, physics, fluid-simulation, soft-body

I was watching a [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zu99qv24FN8&t=61s) for an animated short film and there was a moment when a green pod split open and a person fell out, along with a bunch of fluid. I've set up the link so it begins on the exact part I'm talking about. (Edit) I've also made gifs of the scenes featuring it, as best I can. Also, I use Blender 2.8 and while I'm sure I could find the equivalent settings to the 2.79 ones after a ton searching, I'd prefer it if an answer were written for 2.8.

[image: example_0] [image: example_1]

I really like this effect and I want to recreate this animation; my best guess is use a fluid sim with a soft body sim but I have no clue how; I'm pretty inexperienced with sims.

Comment: Well, you are expecting a full blown tutorial here. I don't think it's gonna happen. In the meantime you can find answers/tutorials that will help you create what you need. Soft Body (bake) > Fracture modifier > Fluid (high viscosity). Too many topics to create one sane answer with your "expectations". Try maybe to part this question for: How to make soft body pod? How to fracture pod? How to make dense fluid?

Comment: @cgslav Sorry, I should have explained my expectations better; that's on me. What I mean by clear and concise instructions isn't me asking for a step by step tutorial of every single component. The stuff like 'how to make a soft body fracture' or 'how to make a viscous fluid' is stuff that is most likely already answered and I can easily find by searching stack exchange or the answer could reference those other questions with links. The 'step by step tutorial' that I'm looking is on how to pull it all together as one project and make all the simulations/modifiers interact properly.

Comment: What part of this are you currently struggling with? How far have you got? It seems that you're expecting someone to produce you a fully formed solution to the whole thing - specific to your particular need. Split your problem into the individual elements, give it a try yourself and if (when?) you get stuck, then post a *specific* question about overcoming that particular hurdle. This will produce questions that are more manageable as well as being more applicable to other people's problems, making any answer far more valuable to the community. As it stands I think this question is off topic.

Comment: @RichSedman Fair enough, I'll concede to that point. Little disappointing that I wasted a bunch of rep on this though, but 'eh, so be it. Anyways, I'm not entirely sure if it would be appropriate to delete this post because of those reasons or if I should request someone with the required privileges to close it, since SE generally seems to discourage users from deleting material.

Comment: Don't worry about the rep - all is not lost - and don't delete. You could edit your question to narrow it down to one specific part of your problem while still referencing the overall goal. You can add multiple questions, one for each step along the way to the final goal. If you manage to solve any of the problems yourself, add your own answer and you'll gain reputation for any upvotes on your questions and answers. The narrower questions will be more applicable to other people's situations and you're much more likely to get results.

Answer (score 1):

I would say make a hollow softbody (I guess with the boolean), make it breakable ([how do I make an object bend or break if hit with sufficient force?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6686/how-do-i-make-an-object-bend-or-break-if-hit-with-sufficient-force) - see the bottom of the first answer), then add fluid inside (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gM8yEMFMjg). I'm not that experienced with those, but I'll do some experimenting and get back to you if i get anything useful.