# How to mask mesh using an object

Tags: cloth-simulation, masking, id-mask

I am running a cloth simulation on a human avatar. I want to hide the human mesh that is underneath the cloth and not the entire human mesh. Is it possible to do something like this using the modifiers available?

Ideal scenario would be to hide/delete the human mesh points under the cloth. But if this is achievable just in the final render, that will also serve the purpose.

[How to use a mesh to reveal an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61448/how-to-use-a-mesh-to-reveal-an-object)
This link seems relevant but here, the cube is made invisible.Also, I'm not looking for an animation, but more like a static change.

Comment: Have you looked at the Mask Modifier and vertex groups yet? I thought this was a simple method before, and saw it in use on the Sintel stuff.

Comment: Yes I did. I used the difference option in mask modifier but couldn't get the desired result.