# Boolean Modifer + Animation Problem

Tags: animation

I am currently using a Boolean Modifier to animate half of object to disappear. I have already tried a fading away affect with a transparent Shader, but it takes about 5 hours to render each frame doing it that way.

Anyway, this is what happens when I render it. This is a quick test one, in low quality.

I am using cycles Render.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Boolean Modifier often generates bad topology. To avoid this, you must be careful in many aspects (sadly it is sometimes inevitable). Would you mind taking screenshots of the topology?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/N2lmq

Here is a screenshot of the top layer. I know that is a lot of polys but the client kept asking for it to be more smoother. Each object was split from the original one when I finally created the design.

Comment: I do not feel comfortable sharing the original file/s as this is a job. Could you link me to a better way to animate the effect I am trying to apply here?

Comment: Booleans have issues with faces that are almost on the same place read the section on overlapping geometry in this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/boolean-modifier-not-working seems to me that the cutting object could be a larger and simpler object.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1853/animating-slicing-up-an-object/1855#1855

Comment: What do you use to bool the eye?

Comment: 2 Boxes that animate towards the left. One removes the first layer of objects and the second removes the bottom layer.

Comment: I have checked my normal and everything seems alright. Would it be best for me to do what one discussion said and. "make an object for each frame"?
That's about 70 frames there. Would it be best for me to do that?

Comment: If you don't mind using an OSL shade why not try the Cutatway shader? https://blendbits.blogspot.com.au/2017/02/the-cutaway-shader-free-blender-add-on.html It can do boolean-like effects without changing geometry. You can use it to cut holes in anything.

Comment: Thank you for the add 3pointedit. I might consider this plugin. However, I would still like the effect that the Boolean gives me. Where it makes the end that it is cutting solid and not open.

Comment: using a bigger box might help. If you are going for the "make for each frame", you should try that on frames with bad results( I guess that's no more than 10 frames) OpenGL rendering might be useful during the task

Comment: I realise you probably want to do this in Cycles and peel back 'physical' mesh, but in the interests of getting your job out, would a curved sliding mask that still gives spherical thickness not be an alternative?  

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cx8d7bkznlfpee4/Eyeball.mp4?dl=0

The inner sphere is pre-cut but another mask could reveal that progressively, as done with the white outer.  Animation time?  10 secs x 2 + another 2 for the final render.

Render was OpenGL for the masking & the internal render for the final mix.  I imagine cycles can do this and lot more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Boolean modifier is not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/the-boolean-modifier-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same problem today. I think the real solution is to use something like the cut-away shader mentioned in the comments, but there is a bit of a hack which worked for me.

Basically, if you play through the animation quickly, EEVEE is very useful for this, there are a relatively small number of frames where the boolean seems to have no effect at all. If you just jiggle the boolean a tiny bit, either by slightly changing the position, scale, etc., it will fix the problem. Then, you can just keyframe the change you made and keep walking though the animation fixing any problem frames.

This is definitely a hack, which is why using some other method is preferable, but it works well enough and is very easy. You will want to play back through the animation before rendering, however, as it is possible one of the new keyframes you introduced caused the boolean to have the same problem in an earlier frame. This happened for me on one frame, and after keying this away, the animation worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I had the same bug still in blender 2.82 while trying to cut out a section of an ocean modifier, thought I'd share my workaround. I found that jiggling the boolean didn't work in my case. What did end up doing the trick was just adding a second boolean with a new shape and parenting it to the buggy boolean target. The glitchy frames went away when I did this.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Could you explain in more detail how you did that? Perhaps illustrate with an image or two.